# I am looking for the title of a book about parallel universes, one with unicorns

Tags: story-identification, novel

In this story, one of the main character, I believe the name is Sheen, travels through portals between worlds, in one of them she meets a unicorn. It is part fantasy, part sci-fi. The character discovers during her journey that she is a robot (a machine, hence her name). I recall a cover with the face of the character, with blue color. The book must have been from before 2010, I would guess between 1980 and 2000.

Comment: Wait, you are saying there are no unicorns in this universe??? Sadness…

Comment: I have closed your question as a Duplicate. This is not a censure, just an indication that we've had this question before, and it's been answered (sometimes, remembering different details). You will still receive points for upvotes, and people can comment on it, but no more answers can be provided.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Piers Anthony's [Apprentice Adept](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apprentice_Adept) series, probably *Split Infinity*:

> The Game-champion serf Stile is assaulted on Proton by an unknown
> enemy, but learns he can escape into a mysterious fantasy world
> (Phaze). In Phaze he meets Neysa, a **unicorn**, and learns of his magical
> legacy as the Blue Adept. Back in Proton he tries to uncover his
> enemy, while building a relationship with his **robot** lover, **Sheen**.

Comment: Great, Thank you ! I have been looking for it for a long time. As I had read it in french, I couldn't find the right places to search. The name in french is "l'Adepte Bleu" serie, book title : "L'infini éclaté", in case some further french readers search for this.